# Integrate custom HTML SASS Template In Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, sass

I am trying to integrate a custom html SaaS template in Laravel 7. I have put the template JS and CSS files in public directory and created a master blade in which I have link these js and css files. But somehow it is not working correctly. I do know that there is some issue with the app.js file but I am unable to identify the actual reason.
I will appreciate if anyone can guide me in this regard.

CSS Files Path:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{{ config('site_name')}} | Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url('images/favicon.ico')}}">

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{ url('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{ url('css/icons.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- App Css-->
    <link href="{{ url('css/app.min.css')}}" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @yield('theme_style')
</head>
```

JS Files Path:

```
<script src="{{url('libs/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url('libs/node-waves/waves.min.js')}}"></script>

<!-- apexcharts -->
<script src="{{url('libs/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{url('js/pages/dashboard.init.js')}}"></script>

<!-- App js -->
<script src="{{url('js/app.js')}}"></script>
@yield('theme_script')
```

The blade is loading but functionality related to some css and js is not working. All the files are linked correctly and loading in view page source.

Note: I also try 'npm run dev' to compile the files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this question, actually I was using url() helper function for linking css/js path. I made two changes to my files:

```
1) I put all files in a folder as it was placed in a default html template.
2) I used URL::asset() OR asset() helper function to link my files.
```

After that i clear the cache and run the project. It just worked.